# SQL Update each row until none of them are 0

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use the following code to update a column in each of my rows until none of them are 0 (The default value). Here's my code:

```
 UPDATE PERSON
 WHILE  = 0
 SET TEAM = 1
 WHERE TEAM = 0;
```

Comment: `update person set team=1 where team=0` will update all the rows where `team=0`. No need for a `WHILE` unless you were doing something that depended on the previous item being set.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `while`, also the syntax is wrong for plsql block

```
UPDATE PERSON     --UPDATING TABLE PERSONS
SET TEAM = 1      
WHERE TEAM = 0;   --WHEN IT'S 0 IT UPDATES
```

The above query will do what you asked.
Should work for mysql and oracle.

Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop SQL can handle this in a single command.

```
UPDATE Person SET Team = 1 WHERE Team = 0
```